# How do I delete a Firebase product (or feature) from a project (e.g. Cloud Storage)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Firebase has 24+ [products/features](https://firebase.google.com/products-build) (e.g. Realtime Database, Cloud Functions, Cloud Storage, etc.), also listed under "Product categories" in the navigation pane. I accidentally hit "Get started" on the Cloud Storage option:

[image]

It's now configured for my project and can incur costs:

[image]

I want to completely delete the "Cloud Storage" product from my project so that I don't need to worry about it incurring unintended costs. I don't want to delete my project as I have other products I want to continue using. Is there a way to delete/disable a specific product on my project (e.g. Cloud Storage) once I enable it, or am I stuck with it until I delete my project?

**Note:** I know I can hide it from the shortcuts list using "Hide shortcut", but this simply hides it from the list. It doesn't actually delete the product, so it could still incur costs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the "Get Started" button for Cloud Storage for Firebase what it does is it [sets up a default bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) for you to store files.

A quick and easy way for you to remove Cloud Storage from your project is to [delete that bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-buckets):

1. Go to [Google Cloud console > Cloud Storage > Buckets](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser).
2. Make sure you have selected the correct project on the dropdown at the console's top bar:[image: Screenshot of the cloud console's topbar]
3. Find the default bucket that was created for your project on the list of buckets (usually follows the pattern `{project-id}.appspot.com`):
   [image: Screenshot showing the default bucket on the list of buckets]
4. Select the checkbox for that bucket and click "delete" at the top of the page:
   [image: screenshot showing the option to delete the bucket]
5. Confirm the deletion on the dialog that pops up.

If you return to the Firebase Console you'll once again see the "Get Started" button on the [Storage tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/storage).

Comment: Thanks! I deleted both `{project-id}.appspot.com` and `staging.{project-id}.appspot.com`, and now I see the "Get Started" again.